# Using Office.onReady() Breaks Outlook 2013 add-ins

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We're building an Outlook add-in, and recently a customer reported that it does not load in Outlook 2013. I've been able to confirm this locally across a number of different versions of our Add-in. It loads and works fine in Outlook 2016, Outlook Web and Outlook for Mac.

We recently changed from Office.initialize to Office.onReady in order to simplify platform detection. This does not work for Outlook 2013. On the face of it, the problem appears to be that the HostType is coming back as Excel, and many of the API's under Office.context (e.g. diagnostics, roamingSettings, mailbox) are undefined.

If I set the entry-point up using Office.initialize, then everything works fine. If setup using Office.onReady, the add-in will load, so long as all the Office api calls have guardrails around them. This lets me get *some* context out, as I can access our internal logging system.

Is this a known issue? Our add-in is now completely broken in Outlook 2013.

**Update:** I previously believed this to be an issue with both onReady and initialize, however I've since found that initialize does in fact still work. It is only onReady that appears to be broken in Outlook 2013

Comment: Thanks for noticing. We're looking into this. Is it correct to say the issue only affects when add-in is running on Windows platform (for Office 2013)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Outlook 2013 on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [identified as a bug](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/301) in the Office-JS API and a fix is incoming.

To work around the issue in the meantime, you can continue to use `Office.initialize`. You can get the context provided by onReady's info parameter using `Office.context.diagnostics`